# Full-text search does not work if query begins from 0

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a table with users and their addresses. Some flats looks like "p06"

This query does not find **anything**:

```
SELECT username, address FROM base WHERE MATCH (username,address) AGAINST ('+Wash* +36 +06' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This query finds "Washington street, h.36, fl.p06":

```
SELECT username, address FROM base WHERE MATCH (username,address) AGAINST ('+Wash* +36 +p06' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

But this query finds **only** Washington street, h.36, fl.6:

```
SELECT username, address FROM base WHERE MATCH (username,address) AGAINST ('+Wash* +36 +6' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

This query works well and finds Washington street, h.36, fl.16:

```
SELECT username, address FROM base WHERE MATCH (username,address) AGAINST ('+Wash* +36 +16' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

p.s. ft_min_word_len = 1

**I wish to get all results by query "+Wash* +36 +6". And find "Washington street, h.36, fl.p06" by query "+Wash* +36 +06"**

Sure it could be wrong queries for my task

Comment: May be you should use `+Wash* +36 +*06`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB?

What is the min-word-length?

In InnoDB, with `innodb_ft_min_token_size` > 2, the `+xx` leads to finding nothing.  Here's the logic:  `+` says that it *must* find the the word `xx`.  However the token size says that the "word" `xx` is not indexed.

Note:  I think MyISAM was more lenient.

One workaround:  When building the `AGAINST` string, don't prepend `+` to any 'word' shorter than min-token-size.  (I actually have an app that uses this trick; I am happy with the results.)

`*06` does not work in `FULLTEXT`

Under no circumstances can you get `FULLTEXT` to find `pxx` by searching for `xx`.

The `0` is irrelevant.  (If it is relevant, please rephrase the Question with a suitable example.)